# Python list comparison operators < and > - How do they work between two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How comparison operators(`<` and `>`) work between two lists? After compare there is always single bool return `True/False`, but do they compare each element or at least one element should be greater/lesser or what? :O

Example : Let's assume i have two lists

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5]
```

When i use `>` greater than/lesser than `<` i have this results :

```py
>>> a > b
False
>>> a < b
True
```

It looks intuitive, because every element in `b`  is greater than same index element in `a`. Now I'll do it with slightly modified `b` list.

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [3, 0, 0]
>>> a > b
False
>>> a < b
True
```

Only first `b` element is bigger than first `a` element, so why `a<b` is still `True`?

Comment: Lists are compared pair-wise, it'll only compare the second elements if the first ones are equal.

Comment: For better clarity, could you post is as an answer and i will accept it?

Comment: Yes indeed! This is the question and answer i was looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Comparing Sequences and Other Types](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)?